# how to get username into sql trigger when multiple users signed on from asp membership

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to log all the changes to database but was unable to find a way to get current username to the trigger. I have `triggerData` table which stores the information of user 
`(guid (userid), data (username), logintime)` these are inserted when user sign in.

Here is the trigger

```
declare @UserIsOnlineTimeWindow DateTime
    declare @currenttime DateTime
    set @currenttime = GETDATE()
    set @UserIsOnlineTimeWindow = 10

    DECLARE @uname nvarchar(max)
    **set @uname = (SELECT T.UserName from (SELECT distinct u.UserName FROM aspnet_Users u
    WHERE IsAnonymous = 'FALSE' AND ((@currenttime - @UserIsOnlineTimeWindow) < u.LastActivityDate)) as t,
    TriggerData td, aspnet_Users au 
    WHERE t.UserName = td.Data and td.guid = au.UserId and td.logintime = (select MAX(td.logintime) from TriggerData td))**

    DECLARE @ComputerName nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @IPAddr nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @BroadcastIP nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @auditInsert nvarchar(255)
    SET @ComputerName = (SELECT ComputerName FROM inserted)
    SET @IPAddr = (SELECT ISNULL(IPAddr,0) FROM inserted)
    SET @BroadcastIP = (SELECT ISNULL(BroadcastIP,0) FROM inserted)
    SET @auditInsert =  @ComputerName+' '+@IPAddr+' '+@BroadcastIP
    Begin

    INSERT INTO Audit(OldInfo ,NewInfo,[User],Date1,Type,TableName) VALUES('New Record',@auditInsert, @uname ,GETDATE(),'Added','LabIP')

    End
```

The query for the username does not give the currently modifying user instead it gives the recently logged in user. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're basic assumptions about triggers are wrong; you seem to assume a trigger is called **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case - the trigger is called **once per batch** and the `Inserted` pseudo table *can* (and **will**) contain **multiple rows**! So you cannot just do a `SELECT ComputerName FROM Inserted` - which of the 55 rows being inserted is being used here? You need to write your trigger so that it can deal with multiple rows in the `Inserted` table!

Comment: I am new to triggers but what I have for now works as I wanted for the trigger to do except getting the correct username. Thanks for the help! Oh now I understand, I have gridview for the data to insert so only one row is inserted at a time may be that is the reason it is working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like marc_s said triggers can and will be applied once per batch.  In your case however it sounds like your current application is only inserting once per batch so it's working fine.  Your will have a problem however if anyone tries to insert more than one row.  Say from another part of the application, or from a query window.  It's really up to you if you want to fix it now or wait for it to break (if ever).

I've re-formated the query that is giving you problems.

```
set @uname = (SELECT T.UserName FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT u.UserName 
        FROM aspnet_Users u
        WHERE IsAnonymous = 'FALSE' 
          AND ((@currenttime - @UserIsOnlineTimeWindow) < u.LastActivityDate)) AS t
        JOIN TriggerData td
          ON t.UserName = td.Data 
        JOIN aspnet_Users au 
          ON td.guid = au.UserId 
        WHERE td.logintime = (select MAX(td.logintime) from TriggerData td))
```

You can see from this where your problem is.  If you look in the WHERE clause you will see that you are specifically pulling the row that last logged in.  If you are not using an application id (although it sounds like you are) you can use USER_NAME() or SUSER_SNAME() to pull the current user.  Unfortunatly based on the information you have provided I don't think you will be able to pull the user that actually made the change, again assuming that you are using an application id.

You might try putting the SPID (id for the current connection) into your users table.  You can retrieve this as @@SPID.  That way while you are in the current connection you will always be able to tell who the current user is.  Of course this will only work if you are holding onto the connection for the whole time the user is logged in (probably not in a web based application).

Last (and unfortunatly least) is rather than using triggers create stored procedures to do your inserts.  Pass in the current user into the SP as part of the parameter list and do your logging there.

Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer +1 for that. I understood what he said, the application is web based user has only one way to insert so right now I don't worry about that. Actually I migrated from Access to SQL so new to this, User_Name and SUSER_SNAME() gives the database user but I have asp membership table for the users and coming to SPID I am not really sure about it but I'll try adding it to the TriggerData table and use that in my where clause. Will let you know soon. Thanks Again!

Comment: I tried SPID, I think it gives the processID of the sql server and does not change according to the user. I don't think that works for the web based. Do you know any other way to get the current user inside trigger

Comment: I didn't really think the SPID idea would work for a web based app but it was worth a try, and again I'm guessing that you are using an app ID.  Your best bet is going to be to do an abstraction layer of SPs.  Have separate SPs for insert, update and delete for each table.  Then call those to do your work.  One of the parameters for each SP will be the user name.  Do your logging in the stored procedures.  Unfortunately with web apps each "hit" to the database tends to be separate from the original connection with the login.  This makes it very difficult if not impossible to connect the two.

Comment: hey thanks for the help, I added an updatedBy column to all tables and  used the Session Parameter for username in asp when pushing insert or update or delete which works. Thanks for the idea of adding username to SP that lead me to this. Thanks Again!

Comment: Just a suggestion but you could also add an updatedDate at the same time.  It can come in handy.

Comment: yeah true but I have date column in audit table so I can retrieve that, don't wanna redo it. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey I have quick question, I updated trigger to handle multiple rows using db cursor but the trigger is not getting fired may be because the firetriggers option have to be enabled and that is done in bulkinsert where as I am doing normal insert, do you have any suggestion for this? Thanks!

Comment: Any non-bulk insert should trigger any enabled insert trigger on that table.  Make sure you trigger is enabled, make sure you aren't short-circuiting the trigger accidentally.

Comment: I think there was some problem with my code I guess, I am not using cursor now instead inner join on original table and the rowcount which is working :D , but still I am not doing bulk insert I have to test that as well. Thanks for the reply.