# How to pass external parameters to triggers in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to write a trigger which accepts external parameters?

While storing the history data, I want to store the Application User Name who has done the Update operation. I thought to use `User_Name()` but came to know that, it only returns the database user, NOT the application user.

Therefore, I am looking for some suggestions on creating triggers with external parameters so that I can pass the application user's id to this trigger. Think I have clearly explained my needs. Thanks in advance !

Here is my code what i have tried....

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Audit]
ON [dbo].[MIS_Opus] FOR UPDATE  
AS  
BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE(), @u SYSNAME = SUSER_SNAME();  
Insert into dbo.MIS_OpusAuditTrigger  
(  
OpusId, Category, ProcessName, DOP, RampupCode, _Count, TimeTaken, Remarks, Audit_Action,    Audit_Timestamp, Changed_By  
)  
SELECT   
       OpusId,  
       Category,  
       ProcessName,  
       DOP,   
       RampupCode,   
       _Count,   
       TimeTaken,  
       Remarks,  
       'before update',  
       @d,  
       @u  
    FROM deleted -- <--- ****** deleted ******   
  UNION ALL   
  SELECT   
      OpusId,  
       Category,   
       ProcessName,   
       DOP,  
       RampupCode,  
       _Count,   
       TimeTaken,   
       Remarks,   
       'After update',   
       @d,   
       @u   
    FROM inserted;  
END
```

In the above code the database user id only stored i need to store the user's id who did update operation. I am using MSSQL server 2012 Please tell how to do it...

Comment: I'm assuming this is about MSSQL. You should add the appropriate version to the question's tags.

Comment: How is the _application user_ defined? Is there any mapping between the _application users_ and the database ones?

Comment: @geomagas I am using MSSQL server 2012

Comment: @geomagas I can,t get your question.Mapping means, i need some example

Comment: @geomagas In the Changed_By column i need user's id who updated the table.

Comment: Does each "application user" correspond to a database user? Is this 1-to-1? Is this stored in a table or something?

Comment: @geomagas Yes the application user information is stored in aspnet_Users table

Comment: See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842412/how-to-get-username-into-sql-trigger-when-multiple-users-signed-on-from-asp-memb).

Comment: @geomagas Is there any possible to solve the solution. I need User's Id(Employee Id) in the Changed By column of trigger table..

Comment: @geomagas That link does not help me

Comment: @geomagas Thanks for the link. I have got some idea from that link. I am going to use SP to store UserName...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need column in the main table that you update for Changed_By user. In that case you can easily put that in audit table. There is no other way to do this because usually web application uses one SQL Server user to work with database.

Another option is to have SQL user for each web application user - but this is insane in my opinion.

Comment: _That's_ insane? That's the only rational way to do it, _if you have access to db security_! _"usually web application uses one SQL Server user to work with database"_ because they're on _shared hosting_! That's a tradeoff, not a feature, nor a "best practice" of sorts!!!

Comment: I don't fully agree with you. If we speak about Enterprise application which uses Windows security, yes. But if you have internet application which is accesses by several hundred thousands of users - in that case I don't think this is the way. Also it is not compromise - there are application roles and users which can be used only from web application.

Comment: By "uses Windows security" I assume you mean SSPI. What difference does that make? Can't "Interner applications" use SSPI? Either way, the security benefits are huge. And _it is a tradeoff_, because your shared host usually _does not allow you to tamper with DB security (users, permissions and the like)_. If they did, noone would have to reinvent the wheel and maintain a custom `users` table, nor would have to hash passwords, nor re-implement ACLs in the app level nor... nor... _No-one!_

Comment: Yes, by Windows security I mean SSPI. And I agree that there is no sense to reinvent the wheel, but I continue to think that SSPI is not applicable for big web applications. Not for every case.

Comment: Well, I've done it. Works perfectly. Had to write nearly _half the code_. Big or small is irrelevant. In fact, the bigger the application, the more benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context_info variable to pass the application user information from the application and use it in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. You can include "Application Name=MyAppName;" in the connection string. After that it is also possible to use that value in SQL batches or SPROCs with the command:

```
SELECT APP_NAME();
```